# Getting a parameter from an endpoint python flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to get 2 parameters from this URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/code=EULPK3PWJC1OLDY16UCLDKEZGUDLXUOYMP&state=342725139626065920

The parameters I am trying to get are code and state. The URL cannot be changed its an endpoint.

So far I came up with this code but it’s not working:

```
@app.route("/login/<string:code><int:state>", methods=['GET'])
def login(code, state):
    print(code, state)
```

and I am getting this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in **call**
>   return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
>   response = self.handle_exception(e)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
>   reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
>   raise value
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
>   response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64>\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
>   return self.finalize_request(rv)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
>   response = self.make_response(rv)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2098, in make_response
>   "The view function did not return a valid response. The"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The view function did not return a valid response.

When accessing the defined route, a return value is expected.
You can return JSON, simple strings or HTML (render_template).

Example for that:

```
@app.route("/login/<string:code><int:state>", methods=['GET'])
def login(code, state):
    return {"Code": code, "State": state}
```

EDIT:

```
@app.route("/login/", methods=['GET'])
def login():
   code = request.args.get('code')
   state = request.args.get('state')
   return {"Code": code, "State": state}
```

Comment: i am grtting a 404 from this http://127.0.0.1:5000/login?code=EUU0V1OPBNSAJ2XZOF6OFLVSHDLPBS5LNV&state=342725139626065920

Comment: Me too. When using more than one parameter I'd suggest you to use the snippet in the answer (I edited it).